# Setting a Php variable to a parameter

Tags: php, javascript

I need to set a Php variable according to a param name.

Javascript Code:

```
<param name="movie" value="....;">
```

located in a separated external js file

I took the value out, since it will be dynamic.

My attempts:

```
$movie = $_GET["movie"]
```

I tried the above but it didn't work.

Am able to set a id to the above param, because then I could call the id

Comment: this is not javascript code: <param name="movie" value="....;">

Comment: its generated within a js code and places into a div called "apdiv1" so its located in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$movie = $_GET["movie"];
<param name="<?php echo $movie; ?>" value="....;">
```

Comment: the javascript is in a js external file so I can't use Php within it, is it possible to set a id to it?

Comment: Not sure. but you could add ".php" to the js file, so you'd have something like "myfile.js.php".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your param tag resides in an object tag for some kind of Flash movie, the actual parameter value is never passed as a get variable. How have you come across the param tag - did you print it yourself? If so, you already have access to the required data. Since you're using PHP, I am assuming that you printed the parameter at some point.

EDIT:
Since JavaScript is used to set the param value, this must occur after the page has been generated by php - meaning its too late to pass variables within the same script. What you can do is pass it as a GET variable from within the same JavaScript function used to set the value in an Ajax call to a dedicated php file to handle such requests. This php file can then generate output and you can then put this output on the current page. See:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Assuming movie_id has the value in it:

```
jQuery.get('movie.php?id=' + movie_id, function(data) {
    jQuery('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

In movie.php:

```
If ( isset($_GET['movie_id']) ) {
    $movie_id = $_GET['movie_id'];
} else {
    // no movie
}
```

Comment: the javascript external file runs and then set the value to the param once it finished loading, also then the param you see above is generated to the html file.

Comment: but I need the dynamical value to then be stored within a database, so I'm using php to add the param value to the database but it doesn't work the way I tried